# Android application doesn't close

Tags: android, dalvik

I've written an application for Android, but it doesn't close and it also starts automatically with the system. I don't know why, but it can't be closed, even through the Task Manager. So I would like to know why it doesn't close.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you have read how Android apps aren't really supposed to close. That aside, I also needed my app to terminate when no longer visible. First I tried

```
System.exit();
```

That worked just fine but it isn't the proper way to do it, the best way is to call

```
finish();
```

I'm sorry if you had already tried/were aware of those solutions; it wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: Also as far as starting automatically with the system, I don't think its supposed to/can do that without an intent filter in the manifest, something like:

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`
which I think you would know if you had or not.

Comment: Technically though, `finish()` only destroys the Activity. It doesn't terminate the whole application.

Comment: Ah yes thats true, I was assuming the app only had one activity.